# What is the meaning of this regular expression?

Tags: regex

```
/\s/g
```

What is the meaning of the above regular expression?

Comment: Um, it's just **one token** and **one flag**. You can **search**.

Comment: You can refer to this cheat sheet about RegExp for trivial information : http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't see why it isn't as valid a question as any other. Especially considering that, with the first answer it got being incorrect, there's obviously room for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means search for a whitespace character. The `/g` means nothing in a single regex search.

**Edit:** You wanted a dissection. Here goes.

```
/
```

Start the regular expression.

```
\
```

A backslash is used to either escape special characters (that, on their own, would change how the regular expression operates, like how a `+` is used to denote "match one or more of the character right before me") or start a metacharacter. In this case, it's used to start a metacharacter:

```
s
```

Coupled with the backslash, the `s` means "match a whitespace character". Whitespace characters are spaces, tabs, newlines, and other such characters.

```
/
```

End the regular expression. OR DOES IT?

```
g
```

Hey what's going on here, CanSpice? I thought you said that `/` ended the regular expression? Well kind reader, this is what's called a "regular expression modifier". It means something like "search globally", and modifies the behaviour of the regular expression. In Perl, for example, it means something like "store the position of the match and start from that position again if we run the match again", so you can do things like:

```
my $x = "cat dog house";
while ($x =~ /(\w+)/g) {
    print "Word is $1, ends at position ", pos $x, "\n";
}
```

...which prints out:

```
Word is cat, ends at position 3
Word is dog, ends at position 7
Word is house, ends at position 13
```

For more, please see [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: can you explain a bit more by dissecting it?

Comment: The `/g` (not `\g`) modifier does not "mean nothing". In some implementations, `'some string with many spaces'.replace(/\s/, '')` will have different results than `'some string with many spaces'.replace(/\s/g, '')`.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: On its own, it means nothing. The questioner didn't say how he's using the regular expression, so I'm not about to infer meaning. If he'd wrapped it in some kind of `replace()` function then yes, it would mean something, but on its own it doesn't. I hope my dissection and analysis of the `g` modifier helps explain this.

Comment: Try `$s="something" ; while ( $s =~ /(\w)/g ) { print "$1\n"}` with and without the /g and decide whether it still means nothing

Comment: @justintime: By any chance did you happen to read my dissection where I covered that exact case? Also, did you happen to read where I said "in a single regex search"? Doing `while(regex)` isn't a single regex search, it's doing multiple searches.

Comment: +1 for a truly thorough explanation, which is even more impressive considering the single-character subject. :)

Comment: Mr. CanSpice. I truly appreciate your time. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CanSpice - I thing your improved answer and my comment were at aboutthe same time. I rememeberyou answer as being shorter :-)